# Declare a private String array and initialization of array elements giving an error

Tags: java, arrays

I declare an array like this

```
    private String[] phoneNumber = new String[3];

    phoneNumber[0] = {"hi"};
    phoneNumber[1] = {"hello"};
    phoneNumber[2] = {"hola"};
```

IDE says "Unknown class: 'phoneNumber'"

There is something dumb I am doing but I did not get it so I come for a help.

Some questions raise to my is below:
1) Array cannot be declare as String?
2) If the answer to the first question is yes, then how?
3) What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @shmosel Error is still there even if I remove curly braces.

Comment: In your code, you don't need the curly braces around the values;  just `phoneNumber[0] = "hi";` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an initialization block to do that, like

```
private String[] phoneNumber = new String[3];
{
    phoneNumber[0] = "hi";
    phoneNumber[1] = "hello";
    phoneNumber[2] = "hola";
}
```

**or** use the shorter array literal syntax. Like,

```
private String[] phoneNumber = { "hi", "hello", "hola" };
```

Comment: Yes Your answer solve the problem. Thank you. For primitive type we do not need block.  So, why we need the initialization block for String?

Comment: You don't. See the literal array syntax. If you said `private int example;` it would get a default initial value of `0`. So it isn't clear how "we do not need a block" for primitive types...